# Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/net/tun: No such device

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn

Previously I've already been able to connect to my server with openVPN. Now I've set up a new one with the same configuration, if I remember correctly, and on a client when trying to connect I get this:

```
ERROR: Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/net/tun: No such device (errno=19)
Exiting due to fatal error
```

I run it as "sudo openvpn client.ovpn".

Comment: Have you compiled the tun module? `modprobe tun;lsmod |grep tun`

Answer (score 3):

**Enable TUN/TAP device driver support in kernel.**

1. Open kernel menuconfig.
2. Enable Device Drivers -> Network device support -> Universal TUN/TAP device driver support
3. Compile and load the kernel again.

It will work!

Comment: Yes, it works for me. Just don't forget to load `tun` via `modprobe tun` if it didn't load automatically.

Answer (score 1):

This seems a permission issue. I was getting similar problem on my Docker instance, and I solved it using `--privileged` option while executing the docker run command

Answer (score 1):

If the other tricks don't work (in other words, you've already installed the kernel modules, etc), make sure that the line

```
alias char-major-10-200 tunode_tunnel
```

is in `/lib/modules/.../modules.alias`.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes answer is easier than you think. Nowadays rarely (even with systemd), but sometimes you have to simply reboot the machine to get things working. Today it happened to me 3<sup>rd</sup> time and took me another 3 minutes of my life to remind myself about solution. So I'm leaving this note as a reminder to the "mankind" and so that I finally remember that:

if kernel was upgraded and OpenVPN shouts with the error mentioned by OP, reboot the machine and OpenVPN should work.